# Is it always necessary to remove duplicate values in a dataset for data analysis?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I  confuse that should i always remove the duplicate values in a datasets when i work in pandas dataframe.I think i should not remove duplicate values because sometimes these values needed for better analysis.

i already asked my questions.

Comment: That completely depends on the kind of data and analysis you are making and what the meaning of a duplicate entry is.